# How to search for a string in old git changes in VSCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a branch rewriting some code in VSCode. (I have the plugin GitLens installed.) I'm rewriting this one function - let's call it `foo` - and I'm trying to understand where it has been used before.

Is there a way to search for something in the modified / deleted changes in Git using VSCode? I mean like pressing `cmd + shift + f` and then typing the word so you get highlights in all current git changes?

Comment: I've no experience of VSCode, but if you want to fallback to the CLI while trying your way, you could use `git log -Sfoo` (reference: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Sltstringgt)

Answer (score 9):

In [gitlens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) left bottom you can see "SEARCH COMMITS" there you can search in change or commit messages

[image: SEARCH COMMITS]

here is example result when I search class in mvn project

[image: search class keyword]

When I search a function name it also finds

[image: Search function name]